# android studio 4.2 problem in debuggable process

Tags: android

android studio (4.2) no debuggable process after update to 4.2

No debuggable processes in android studio when connected with phone or emulator

when I plug in my phone to debug apps,logcat can detect my phone,but i can not choose process. It said "no debuggable processes".
it happened After updating Android Studio to 4.2

Comment: try `adb kill-server` in terminal

Comment: I did this command before but it does not work

Comment: you don't need to delete @shirley answer just don't approve it, maybe it helped someone although it didn't work for me but let it be!

Comment: She deleted her post herself

Comment: I faced this problem few days ago and I realized that the `Android Device Monitor (DDMS)` works well with no problem. So I think the problem is with new update of Android Studio. You can temporarily use DDMS from `%ANDROID_HOME%/tools/monitor.bat` but I dont know how to fix the bug :(

Comment: I guess downgrade to previous versions of Android Studio may fix the problem. I will inform you if I found the solution. Please tell me if you findout how to solve this. thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68683609/android-studio-2020-3-1-no-debuggable-processes-in-logcat-when-phone-detected

Answer (score 0):

Update:

This is a new bug with local datetime formats (such as Persian in this case) in logcat in Android Studio versions equal or newer than 4.2.

We have to use English (United States) format in region settings to avoid this problem. (Tested in both ver 4.2 and Arctic fox)

Solution: In windows 10 Go to `Control Panel > Region > Formats tab > Change format to English (United States)`

Old answer:

I faced this problem few days ago and I realized that `Android Device Monitor (DDMS)` works well from `%ANDROID_HOME%/tools/monitor.bat` directory with no problem.

So I solved the problem by `downgrading Android Studio from v4.2 to v4.1.3` and now its working fine.

Let me know if you could fix the problem on v4.2.+

Comment: no. i downgrading Android Studio from v4.2 to v4.1.3 too

Comment: @rezakia I found the solution to fix problem on v4.2+ and arctic fox version. read my updated answer.

Comment: thanks alot homayoon.i solved  by using English (United States) format in region settings.thanks again