# Android studio 2020.3.1 No debuggable processes in logcat when phone detected

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

Hellow Everyone!

I have problem with new version of `android studio 2020.3.1` and `android studio 4.2.2`. when I plug in my phone to debug apps, logcat can detect my phone, but I can not choose process. It said "`no debuggable processes`",not common "no debuggable applications".

I don't think there is a problem with projects and devices because everything is fine on version `4.1` of Android Studio and this problem only occurs on version `2020.3.1`.

This is a problem for all devices and all projects.
I checked all the following but the problem was not resolved:

1- debuggable in enable in gradle

2- choose debug in build variant

3- kill adb and strart it again

4-  invalidate cache

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For developers who are living in `Iran` it's related to `sanctions`. after `version 4.2` is released google use more ways to identify where we are come from and two possible of them is Region and Regional Format. therefore You should change them to another country and then update sdk to solve the problem.

for change region to `united states` in `windows 10` :

setting -> time & language -> region -> select `united states` in country or region drop down .

Comment: This also solves another problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68973640/android-studio-layout-designer-creates-numbers-in-persian/69222505#69222505

Comment: I think this is a new bug with local datetime formats in logcat and is not a new sanction against Iranian developers. We have to use Gregorian calendar to avoid this bug.

Comment: yes and in Arab  countries